# image slider lets pictures go out the border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web site http://www.jccaspen.com/templates/section_cdo/aid/2644906/jewish/Ski-to-Live.htm

There is a slider that i bought and installed. However if you watch the slider on some switches the image will go off the slider border, covering header or content. It makes it very ugly and unprofessional. I already looked at the forums where i bought the slider but no one seemed to have this problem. I dont understand why its happening and especially because there is no exact pattern i can't figure it out. Maybe someone had this kind of problem and knows the solution?

Comment: if there is a container (i say "if" because you've provided no actual code here), set the CSS of that container to include `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I firebugged your test site and just added `overflow: hidden;` to your `.bannercontainer` and it seems to fix your issue (hiding anything that's outside of that container)

Seems like an inline style is applied to your container ... so my guess is that you can either set it as an option (but you haven't let us know what's this slider) or override the CSS rule like that:

```
.bannercontainer {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Let me know if that works !

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. I dont have the overflow:visible as inline style for the container. it somehow gets generated. I tried the code you provided previously but without the !important